# addEdge method for topological order in Java

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, topological-sort

I'm currently having a problem with my `addEdge` method.

`addEdge` is supposed to take in two strings and create an `edgeNode` at the position of the first string parameter and then create an edge between the first parameter and second parameter.

So lets say we have a `vertexNode` that contains `A` and its next value points to a `vertexNode` that contains `B` (think of it as a singly linked list). Now let's say the parameters for `addEdge` are `A` and `B`. Then `addEdge` would add an `edgeNode` at `VertexNode` that contains `A` and this `edgeNode` would point back to `A`'s `VertexNode` and it would point to `B`'s `VertexNode`.

This would also cause the indegree of `B` to increase by 1. I'm currently getting a null pointer error when I call `addEdge` (lines where the error is occuring is marked in code).

Here's my code:

```
public class TopologicalSort {

    private class VertexNode {
        private String name;
        private VertexNode nextV;
        private EdgeNode edges;
        private int indegree;

        private VertexNode(String n, VertexNode v){
            name = n;
            nextV = v;
            edges = null;
            indegree = 0;

        }


    }

    private class EdgeNode {
        private VertexNode vertex1;
        private VertexNode vertex2;
        private EdgeNode nextE;//ERROR NULL POINTER

        private EdgeNode(VertexNode v1, VertexNode v2, EdgeNode e){
            vertex1 = v1;
            vertex2 = v2;
            nextE = e;
        }

    }
    private VertexNode vertices;
    private int numVertices;


    public TopologicalSort(){
        vertices = null;
        numVertices = 0;

    }

    public void addVertex(String s){
        numVertices++;
        if (vertices == null || vertices.name.compareTo(s) > 0){
            vertices = new VertexNode(s,vertices);



        }
        VertexNode temp = vertices;
        while(temp.nextV != null && temp.nextV.name.compareTo(s) <= 0){
            temp = temp.nextV;
        }
        temp.nextV = new VertexNode(s,temp.nextV);






    }


    public void addEdge(String n1, String n2){
        VertexNode v1 = vertices;
        VertexNode v2 = vertices;
        while(vertices != null){
            if(n1.equals(vertices.name)){
                v1 = vertices;
            }
            if(n2.equals(vertices.name)){
                v2 = vertices;
            }
            vertices = vertices.nextV;
        }
        EdgeNode e = new EdgeNode(v1, v2, v1.edges.nextE);//ERROR NULL POINTER
        v1.edges = e;
        v2.indegree++;
    }
```

Anyone know why I'm getting this error?

Comment: Always post the stacktrace when you encounter a runtime exception

Comment: This is because you have never instantiated the `edges` variable.

Comment: What do you mean by this?